# Is it posible to test collision detection between one object and sprites group?

Tags: object, python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection, sprite

Basicly i want to check if player collided with alien bullets,i know you can check collision with spritecollide,but there is only one player so i dont want to create a player sprite group.So how can i check if there is collision between instance of player class and alien_bullets sprite group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for

```
spritecollideany(sprite, group, collided = None)
```